# How to model binomial data when the dependent variable is LITERALLY dependent on the independent variable

Tags: regression, logistic, chi-squared-test, binomial-distribution, predictor

I am designing an experiment where a subject makes a choice between two options ("low value" (LV) and "high value" (HV)).

The subject will experience both options during a trial that takes place before their choice is measured.

I want to test whether subjects choose the HV option.

To avoid any potential effect of which side the option is presented, I intend to switch the HV option from left to right (and vice versa) between first exposure and the choice test trial.

I need to account for subject ID (random effect), so cannot use a simple Chi-square test. I was hoping to use a binomial logistic regression to test whether subjects are more likely to choose the HV option, but obviously this doesn't make sense as the dependent variable is the same as the independent variable.

I thought about using the right-left data instead (i.e. *choose L/R* ~ *HV on L/R*) but I think this would just tell me whether HV being on the right or left makes a difference to the choice, rather than whether the subjects choose the HV option.

Could anyone tell me how I can overcome this issue? Is there an appropriate test out there that can do this with additional variables, or is there a different way I could prepare the data to make it work?

Comment: Do you just want to know if subjects choose HV more often than a 50/50 chance (or whatever your ratio of HV is to LV)?

Comment: Yes. Ideally, I'd just use a chi-square test, but the subjects will be tested multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You have two IV's (Low Value and High Value) and 1 DV which is binary.

Thus, a binary GLM would be appropriate.

Assuming "Low Value" is your baseline, then the coefficient on "High Value" would be the effect of "High Value" vs "Low Value". If the p-value is not significant, then there is no  difference between the "Low Value" and "High Value". You interpret the constant as the baseline for the "Low Value".

The reason this works is because ANOVA and Regression are the same thing. (Try running an ANOVA and a post-hoc test like Tukey's HSD and you will get the same results as would via linear regression).

Thus, you can perform an ANOVA type analysis using GLM's in a similar manner by interpreting the coefficients and p-values. Your treatment groups will be measured against a baseline, etc.

An additional way to interpret this is that since you have a controlled experiment then your IV's are truly independent.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I'm afraid I'm still unsure how I would construct the model. Is there not an issue with the HV and LV options being presented at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Through playing with some dummy data in R and thinking more about the answers/comments here, I think I've figured out the answer to my question. I just need to look at the value of the intercept.

I should use a logistic regression with only the intercept. So, when coding it in R, and with `choice` as the binary dependent variable:

```
    my.model = glmm(choice ~ 1 + (1|subjectID), data = data, family = binomial(link = "logit"))
```

The coefficient for the intercept informs me whether the number of "correct choices" is significantly above 50%.

If I want to include fixed effects and test whether covariates affect `choice`, I would have to compare a model with these with this intercept-only model with anova() or similar.